# Examining a WCF rest service in IE 9

Tags: rest, wcf, internet-explorer-9

I have been playing around with the "WCF Rest Service Template CS (40)" template in VS 2010. For some reason, I am seeing different behaviors when browsing the service between IE9 and IE8.

In IE8, going to, say, http://localhost:port/Service1/ will display the expected XML response with a list of items.

However, in IE9, all I see is a blank page. But, when I View Source, I can see the message there. Does anyone know what I need to change, configuration-wise, in IE9 to make it display the response properly in the browser window? I have been searching all over, in the IE9 forums, WCF, these forums, etc.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Do yourself a favour and spend some time learning how to use fiddler.  Using a browser as a debugging tool will drive you crazy in the long run.

Comment: If you open IE9's F12 developer tools, you'll likely see a console message about XSLT handling. If you push the Compatibility View button, you'll probably see the legacy "pretty print" view.

Answer (score 0):

Open IE -> Internet Options -> Content -> Feeds & Web Slices -> Clear the "Turn on feed reading view".

--larsw